# Docker PHP container throws 200's and 404's

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, nginx

I have this Wordpress + PHP project I'm trying to run in Docker containers. The website does work when you visit it in the browser, but it's extremely slow. I tried changing the PHP container port, didn't work. Also tried adding a cache to the PHP Dockerfile, didn't make it any faster. These are the log files:

```
php_1  | [12-Oct-2020 09:24:13] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
php_1  | [12-Oct-2020 09:24:13] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
web_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
web_1  | 192.168.99.1 - - [12/Oct/2020:09:24:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 66467 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36"
web_1  | 192.168.99.1 - - [12/Oct/2020:09:24:30 +0000] "GET /wp/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css?ver=5.5.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 53907 "http://192.168.99.103:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36"
web_1  | 192.168.99.1 - - [12/Oct/2020:09:24:30 +0000] "GET /wp/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/theme.min.css?ver=5.5.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 2218 "http://192.168.99.103:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36"
web_1  | 192.168.99.1 - - [12/Oct/2020:09:24:30 +0000] "GET /assets/novio/css/tiny-slider.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 2178 "http://192.168.99.103:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36"
web_1  | 192.168.99.1 - - [12/Oct/2020:09:24:30 +0000] "GET /assets/novio/css/styles.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 173264 "http://192.168.99.103:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36"
web_1  | 192.168.99.1 - - [12/Oct/2020:09:24:30 +0000] "GET /assets/novio/css/styles-fa.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 114278 "http://192.168.99.103:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36"
web_1  | 192.168.99.1 - - [12/Oct/2020:09:24:30 +0000] "GET /assets/novio/js/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 85578 "http://192.168.99.103:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36"
web_1  | 192.168.99.1 - - [12/Oct/2020:09:24:30 +0000] "GET /assets/novio/js/main.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 9683 "http://192.168.99.103:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36"
web_1  | 192.168.99.1 - - [12/Oct/2020:09:24:30 +0000] "GET /assets/novio/js/vendor.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 31966 "http://192.168.99.103:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36"
php_1  | 172.31.0.4 -  12/Oct/2020:09:24:16 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
web_1  | 192.168.99.1 - - [12/Oct/2020:09:24:50 +0000] "GET /app/uploads/2020/08/00A7580.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 24328 "http://192.168.99.103:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36"
web_1  | 192.168.99.1 - - [12/Oct/2020:09:24:50 +0000] "GET /app/uploads/2020/09/JEE-O-bloom-setting-3-scaled.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 24328 "http://192.168.99.103:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36"
php_1  | 172.31.0.4 -  12/Oct/2020:09:24:30 +0000 "GET /index.php" 404
web_1  | 192.168.99.1 - - [12/Oct/2020:09:24:50 +0000] "GET /assets/novio/img/logo-white.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 2519 "http://192.168.99.103:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36"
php_1  | 172.31.0.4 -  12/Oct/2020:09:24:30 +0000 "GET /index.php" 404
web_1  | 192.168.99.1 - - [12/Oct/2020:09:24:50 +0000] "GET /app/uploads/2020/09/JEE-O-pure-setting-01-scaled.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 16128 "http://192.168.99.103:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36"
php_1  | 172.31.0.4 -  12/Oct/2020:09:24:30 +0000 "GET /index.php" 404
web_1  | 192.168.99.1 - - [12/Oct/2020:09:24:51 +0000] "GET /app/uploads/2020/09/JEE-O-flow-small-setting-02-scaled.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 16128 "http://192.168.99.103:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36"
php_1  | 172.31.0.4 -  12/Oct/2020:09:24:30 +0000 "GET /index.php" 404
```

This continues for a while with only 404 errors.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  web:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
     - ./:/code
     - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
     - "8080:80"
    links:
      - php

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - TZ=Europe/Amsterdam
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker/sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
           
  php:
    build:
      context: ./docker/php
    ports:
      - "9090:9000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/code
      - ./docker/php/zz-docker.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf
    restart: always
    

volumes:
  wordpress:
  db:
```

nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

    server {

        listen         80 default_server;
        server_name    jeeo.com;
        root           /code/public_html;
        index          index.php;
        try_files $uri index.php;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {

                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass php:9090;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;

            }

    }

}
```

PHP Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:fpm

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
RUN docker-php-ext-install opcache
RUN sed -i 's/9000/9u090/' /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf
```

edit:

zz-docker.conf:

```
[global]
daemonize = no

[www]
listen = 9090
```

Comment: Can you also paste content of `./docker/php/zz-docker.conf`? Error you see is about fpm-pool configuration, that's why it's relevant.

Comment: `php_1  | [12-Oct-2020 08:04:44] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it` - what have you tried to resolve this?

Comment: It's solved, but this issue still stands. I've updated the log file in the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is not related to docker, the problem is in your configuration of php.

From the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/php), you should use production configuration.

```
FROM php:fpm

# Use the default production configuration
RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
RUN docker-php-ext-install opcache
RUN sed -i 's/9000/9u090/' /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf
```

From your logs, you should increase pm.max_children in php.ini:

```
php_1  | [12-Oct-2020 08:04:44] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it
```

More details [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/479443/php5-fpm-server-reached-pm-max-children/578673)

Comment: Thank you! I've tried it, still the same problem. I've updated the log files in the post.